# How to import a function from an other package __init__.py file

Tags: python

I would like to import a function which lives in an `__init__.py` file from **an other, already installed** python package.

If it would be my package, I could import it via

`from . import wanted_function`.

But since it is in an other package, this does not work obviously.

I tried for example

```
from other_package.__init__ import wanted_function
```

but it does not work. Thank you!

Comment: Just `from other_package import wanted_function`…?!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, e.g. `import keras`
`from keras_applications import get_submodules_from_kwargs`.